# How to use given in Dotty?

Tags: scala, sbt, implicit, dotty, scala-3

I was looking at `Dotty` docs under `Contextual Abstractions` page and I saw the `Given Instances`.

> Given instances (or, simply, "givens") define "canonical" values of
>   certain types that serve for synthesizing arguments to given clauses.
>   Example:

```
trait Ord[T] {
  def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
  def (x: T) < (y: T) = compare(x, y) < 0
  def (x: T) > (y: T) = compare(x, y) > 0
}

given intOrd: Ord[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
    if (x < y) -1 else if (x > y) +1 else 0
}

given listOrd[T]: (ord: Ord[T]) => Ord[List[T]] {

  def compare(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): Int = (xs, ys) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => 0
    case (Nil, _) => -1
    case (_, Nil) => +1
    case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
      val fst = ord.compare(x, y)
      if (fst != 0) fst else compare(xs1, ys1)
  }
}
```

But this example from [docs](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/delegates.html) never explains how to use `given`. I pulled the test `Dotty` example project and try yo use it, but I don't quite understand it.

Is it a new keyword ? Do we import it ? Or am I missing something .

Comment: The [first link](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/given-clauses.html) on that page explains

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I must be blind , because I don't see it :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an example of using the `given` instance. Let's say we want to compare two integers, and see which is bigger than the other. We can leverage the already defined `intOrd` above and write:

```
def whichIsBigger[T](x: T, y: T)(given ord: Ord[T]): String = {
  ord.compare(x, y) match {
    case -1 => s"$x is less than $y"
    case 0 => s"$x and $y are equal"
    case 1 => s"$x is greater than $y"
  }
}

println(whichIsBigger(2, 1))
```

Which yields:

```
2 is greater than 1
```

We were able to do this because there was a named given instance in scope, otherwise, the compiler would have complained it doesn't have an `Ord[Int]`.

> Is it a new keyword ? Do we import it ? Or am I missing something.

It is a new keyword, one which replaces a specific part of `implicit` definition in Scala 2. If this was Scala 2, we would have written:

```
implicit val intOrd: Ord[Int] = new Ord[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
    if (x < y) -1 else if (x > y) 1 else 0
}

def whichIsBigger[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit ord: Ord[T]): String
```

Comment: "we would have written" ... worth mentioning where `implicit` would go in `whichIsBigger` esp as `given` is new?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it would be instructive to compare how we might define a typeclass using `implicit` keyword in Scala 2 versus using `given` keyword in Scala 3:

[Scala 2](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6kd1dhlsTvqw4bhHWDuzQA)

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

object Semigroup {
  def combine[A: Semigroup](x: A, y: A) = implicitly[Semigroup[A]].combine(x,y)

  implicit val intSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] = new Semigroup[Int] {
    def combine(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
  }

  implicit val quxSemigroup: Semigroup[Qux] = new Semigroup[Qux] {
    def combine(x: Qux, y: Qux) = Qux(x.a + y.a)
  }
}

case class Qux(a: Int)

Semigroup.combine(41, 1)
Semigroup.combine(Qux(41), Qux(1))
```

[Scala 3](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RJNesafOTC6LkG4cImZOiQ)

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}

object Semigroup {
  def combine[A](x: A, y: A)(given Semigroup[A]) = summon.combine(x,y)

  given intSemigroup: Semigroup[Int] {
    def combine(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
  }

  given quxSemigroup: Semigroup[Qux] {
    def combine(x: Qux, y: Qux) = Qux(x.a + y.a)
  }
}

case class Qux(a: Int)

Semigroup.combine(41, 1))
Semigroup.combine(Qux(41), Qux(1))
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's a new keyword, as you can tell from `'given'` being used in the grammar at the end of the page (section "Syntax"). It is intended to replace `implicit`. If you are already familiar with implicits, I think [Relationship with Scala 2 Implicits](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html) is good to start with.