# How does given keyword work in Scala 3 or dotty?

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, dotty, scala-3

I was going through Scala 3 documentation. They have introduced `given` keyword which is considered as the alternative of Scala 2 `implicit`.
The code is here

```
trait Ord[T] {
  def compare(x: T, y: T): Int
  def (x: T) < (y: T) = compare(x, y) < 0
  def (x: T) > (y: T) = compare(x, y) > 0
}

given intOrd: Ord[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
    if (x < y) -1 else if (x > y) +1 else 0
}

given listOrd[T]: (ord: Ord[T]) => Ord[List[T]] {

  def compare(xs: List[T], ys: List[T]): Int = (xs, ys) match {
    case (Nil, Nil) => 0
    case (Nil, _) => -1
    case (_, Nil) => +1
    case (x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
      val fst = ord.compare(x, y)
      if (fst != 0) fst else compare(xs1, ys1)
  }
}
```

I am very confused here that what is happening here in the bellow code:

```
given intOrd: Ord[Int] {
   def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
   if (x < y) -1 else if (x > y) +1 else 0
}
```

Is it instantiating `Ord[T]` within `given` keyword or something else?

Comment: A little too early to ask this questions TBH. It is not finalized yet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`given` is in this context making `Int` a member of typeclass `Ord` and corresponds to Scala 2 providing a typeclass instance via `implicit` definition

```
implicit object intOrd extends Ord[Int] {
  def compare(x: Int, y: Int) =
    if (x < y) -1 else if (x > y) +1 else 0
}
```

as explained in [Relationship with Scala 2 Implicits](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/relationship-implicits.html#given-instances).

[Scala 3 by Example - better Semigroup and Monoid](https://www.slideshare.net/pjschwarz/scala-3-by-example-better-semigroup-and-monoid) slides by Philip Schwarz have excellent step-by-step and side-by-side comparisons of Scala 2 versus Scala 3 implementations of typeclasses, for example,

[image]

Related question: [How to use given in Dotty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59456843/5205022)

---

Regarding the comment it might early to ask this question, consider similar question by [deusaquilus](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/updated-proposal-revisiting-implicits/3821/238) in [Revisiting Implicits](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/updated-proposal-revisiting-implicits/3821?u=mario-galic)

> Just out of curiosity, are we actually considering changing implicits
>   again between Dotty 0.22 and Scala 3? I’m trying to gauge feature
>   stability and syntax is a large part of that.

to which Odersky [replies](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/updated-proposal-revisiting-implicits/3821/242?u=mario-galic)

> As far as I am concerned I hope that we have reached a fixed point. I
>   am actually quite happy with the current proposal. If someone has a
>   brilliant idea how to improve some aspect of it further over the next
>   weeks I am happy to consider, of course. But my expectation is that we
>   are by and large done now.

Thus it seems `given` will be part of Scala 3.

Comment: Hey [Mario](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5205022/mario-galic) thank you very much for linking to my slide deck :-)